# Can't assign materials to certain vertices, messes up vertex assignment

Tags: modeling, texturing, vertices

I'm trying to assign 2 materials to a soda can model, and every time I assign a material on the top, for some reason it assigns the whole middle section as well. The bottom does this as well sometimes.

[image]

Right now I'm trying to assign the radial material to just the top part of the can.

But for some reason when I assign the vertices to it and click deselect then select, it instead selects all of the vertices in the middle part, like this:
[image]

Comment: Select the faces, select the material you want to assing to those faces and press on the [assign button.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u9us1.png) Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Face material assignment is additive. If you had other faces assigned to the same material before, that assignment is kept. Override the Other faces with the Second material to fix it.